# Small question about the mean not being in its confidence interval

Tags: statistical-inference

To study a certain characteristic about a population of people we take a sample of $100$ individuals. The $80$ percent confidence interval for the mean is $(0.9,1.1)$.

Part I: Find the sample mean and standard deviation (easy). $\bar x = 1$ and $\hat \sigma = 0.7752$

Part II: What is the probability that $(0.9,1.1)$ doesn't contain the mean.

What about Part II? Is it just $1 - 0.8 = 0.2$, or is it a trick question?

Comment: Seems right to me, but I'm only about 80% confident in my answer :P

Comment: @PatrickStevens it seems to me that confusion is normal in such situations

Comment: Maybe they are after a technical point:  There is a standard abuse of language involved here, discussed in (eg) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval .  Once the interval is chosen, there is no probability involved.  The mean is either in it or it isn't.  The "$80\%$" means that the method of choosing the band results in a band which will contain the mean "$80\%$" of the time.

Comment: @George this question is just mean.

Comment: @George Do you see the possible misunderstanding here?  To take a clearer instance:  if you roll a fair die there is a $\frac 16$ chance of getting a $6$.  So, you roll it and you get a $4$.  This does not mean that there is a $\frac 16$ chance that $4=6$.

Comment: i now see what you mean @lulu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 2 isn't a trick question. The answer is 0.2. The trick question which tends to be asked in these situations is "what is the probability $\mu$ lies in the confidence interval?" Then the answer is "either $1$ or $0$, depending on whether it does or does not."

Comment: thank you, but how does the question you suggested differ from that in my post?

Comment: or what is the kind of situation that you are supposing so that this question means something else

Comment: It's all in the wording. In your question, they are referring to the confidence interval as a variable, and the mean is fixed, which is correct. In the trick question, they are implying that the mean is a variable, which it is not.